# ExpressionEngine mod_rewrite Rule to Redirect URLs with Underscores to Dashes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, expressionengine

I'm using ExpressionEngine as my CMS and would like to remove underscores from my site's URLs and replace them with dashes.

For example, I've got a URL that is formatted like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php/menu/friday-lunch
```

To remove `index.php` from the URL, I'm using the following mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Which works, since I can just type in: http://example.com/menu/friday-lunch

On the old site I used underscores instead of hyphens for page URIs, so I wrote a `mod_rewrite` rule to to redirect URIs with underscores to use dashes.

So `friday_lunch` becomes `friday-lunch` using the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

This rule works rather well, except that it 301 Redirects to `example.com/index.php/menu/friday-lunch` instead of `example.com/menu/friday-lunch` — notice the addition of `index.php`.

Here's the entire .htaccess I'm currently using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

How can I redirect all of my URLs with underscores to the equivalent with dashes?

Bonus: to make matters worse, URLs that lead to `/system`, must not be rewritten with a hyphen, e.g.: `example.com/system/login_in/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete set of RewriteRules that should do what you need:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable Apache's RewriteEngine
    RewriteEngine On

    # Ignore Matching Directories
    RewriteRule ^(images|themes|system) - [L,NC]

    # Replace Underscores with Dashes
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]

    # Remove index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

To have your `mod_rewrite` rules ignore the ExpressionEngine `system` folder and not replace underscores `_` with dashes `-` use the following:

`RewriteRule ^(images|themes|system) - [L,NC]`

Dissecting the RewriteRule into plain English:

- The `-` flag instructions Apache to *do nothing*, and **to not rewrite** the URI
- The `L` flags means this should be last rule; ignore everything following
- The `NC` flag means no-case (so "System" or "SYSTEM" is also matched)

This "ignore" rule is especially important and you may need to add additional directories to exclude depending on your directory structure.

Otherwise, you may end up with images and other files saved with underscores that get replaced with dashes.

---

Note: If your URLs contain more than three underscores, you'll need to add another RewriteRule above the existing ones for each [Word Separator for URL Titles](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#word-separator-for-url-titles) you want to replace:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2-$3-$4 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You included 'index.php' in your replacement string.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 -> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1
```

Comment: Yes – but that is a must to remove the index.php in the first place, no?

Comment: Syntax: RewriteRule Pattern Substitution. Your index.php is in the substitution, not the pattern. You possibly want something more like: RewriteRule ^(.*)index/.php\/(.*)$ $1$2. I haven't tested this one but if you get the idea then you can play around with it on your site.